# Flutter: Getting 'null' while decoding the json file while using fromJson() method

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm loading json file like this,

```
Future loadData() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/states.json');
}
```

json data look like this,

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    },
]
```

My model class,

```
class States{
  String name;
  String abbreviation;
  States({this.name, this.abbreviation});

  factory States.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return States(
      name: json['name'],
      abbreviation: json['abbreviation']
    );
  }
}
```

the function where I'm trying printing it,

```
Future<void> search(String text) async {
    String jsonString = await loadData();
    var data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    List<States> states = data.forEach((value) {
      States.fromJson(value);
    });
    print(states.toString());//this is where I'm getting null
}
```

I'm using this function in onChanged in TextFormField widget and loadData() is also in initState so I'm getting json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `map` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` can't return a value.

```dart
List<States> states = data.map<States>((value) {
    return States.fromJson(value);
}).toList();

// only for printing in log
states.forEach((e) => print('${e.name}, ${e.abbreviation}'));
```

Comment: hello thanks for answering, but when I tried your solution then it gives error like 'List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<States>' so i tried adding type after map like this `data.map<States>((value) {
      return States.fromJson(value);
    }).toList();`. but it gives me Instance of States in when I print it

Comment: Yes since `data` is List<dynamic> you need to cast it. Also to print it you need to use forEach, you can't directly use `print` for printing custom objects.

Comment: your answer is correct for my question but can tell if I wanted to use where clause on it how can I do it.

Comment: Awesome! What would you like to do with `where`?

Comment: I want filter this list so that whatever user types it only shows that state. so I want to use it as `states.where((e) => e.name.startsWith(text))` as I'm using it in a textformfield